# Angular Catch global keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keypress

There are so many answers for this question but i can't figure it out how to solve two problems. After research i build very simple directive.

```
.directive('keypressEvents', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function () {
            $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
                alert(e.keyCode);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

First problem is more like a question, if i made it `angular.service('myService', myServiceFunction);`, will it work globally? Second is some key are not working, like ESC, arrows ctrl etc. I am working on this [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/RWWREW)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is really global handler you can bind it to the *$document*. You can add that  in the *run* phase. There you will be able to inject other dependencies that you will need to implement the logic for handling. You can add it also in some service or directive if you think that there belongs more, you don't need to care where because just by binding it to the *$document* will make it global.

Otherwise you can create a directive like yours and bind it to the element. That gives you the option to choose on which element you will add the directive and if it's global then it's enough to add it on the *body* if not then you can choose your container element.

About the second question the event on *Esc* key is not triggered because *Esc* is key not a character. So instead of *keypress* you need to use *keydown* or *keyup* events.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWWddN) is a working example of your code with *keyup* event.

```
$document.bind('keyup', function (e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

I hope that this answer will help you.

Comment: Note that you should unbind this event in your component's $onDestroy method or your scope's $destroy event. Otherwise, you'll be creating a memory leak here.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need something like this [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOOvVJ)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(function () {
  angular.element(document).bind('keyup', function (e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
  });
});
```

Comment: ok, i see your point, i believe better to make it .run() insteed of config, what do you thing?

Comment: For the case you have posted here it doesn't matter. I would not give any further recommendations because I don't know what exactly you are trying to implement. If you want to use any services or providers in your handler it is better to wrap it into service and inject it to run method.

`...run(function(myGlobalKeyHandlerService){  myGlobalKeyHandlerService.start(); })`